# CFPropertyList usage

Tags: php, iphone

i am trying to return a list of users whose accounts have expired from my server to my iphone objective c app using CFPropertyLIst but the data returned in the NSURLConnection callback is always null. I think my use of CFPropertyList may not be correct but can't work out why not

```
$query="SELECT user, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) AS created_ts FROM  accounts"
$result = mysql_query($query)  


$userarray = new CFArray ();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user = $row['user'];
    $created_ts = $row['created_ts'];

   $entry = new CFDictionary();
   $entry->add('user', new CString($user));
   $entry->add('created_ts', new CFNumber($created_ts));
   $userarray->add($entry);

}

$plist = new CFPropertyList();
$plist->add($userarray);
$plist->toXML();
var_dump($plist);
```

Objective C

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // We have got everything so no longer need the connection so release it.
    [theConnection release];
    theConnection = nil;

NSString *errorString = nil;
NSArray *array = [[NSPropertyListSerialization 
                       propertyListFromData:theData
                       mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                       format:nil
                       errorDescription:&errorString] retain];

}
```

Here I'm always getting unexpected character o at line 1 
because the format of the plist looks like this which appears ok but still always getting this error

object(CFPropertyList)#5 (17)
   {
      ["file:protected"]=>   NULL
      ["format:protected"]=>    int(0)
      ["value:protected"]=>    array(1) {
      [0]=>   object(CFArray)#1 (2) 
      {
       ["iteratorPosition:protected"]=>
       int(0)
       ["value:protected"]=>
       array(1) {
       [0]=>  object(CFDictionary)#2 (3) 
        {
          ["iteratorPosition:protected"]=>  int(0)
          ["iteratorKeys:protected"]=>  NULL
          ["value:protected"]=>  array(2) 
          {
            ["user"]=>  object(CFString)#3 (1) {
              ["value:protected"]=>
              string(9) "anonymous"
            }
            ["created_ts"]=>
            object(CFNumber)#4 (1) {
              ["value:protected"]=>
              int(1281263044)
            }
           }
         }
        }
      }
     }
  ["iteratorPosition:protected"]=>  int(0)
  ["iteratorKeys:protected"]=>   NULL
  ["content:protected"]=>  NULL
  ["pos:protected"]=>  int(0)
  ["uniqueTable:protected"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["countObjects:protected"]=>  int(0)
  ["stringSize:protected"]=>  int(0)
  ["intSize:protected"]=>  int(0)
  ["miscSize:protected"]=>   int(0)
  ["objectRefs:protected"]=> int(0)
  ["writtenObjectCount:protected"]=>int(0)
  ["objectTable:protected"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["objectRefSize:protected"]=>int(0)
  ["offsets:protected"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: Have you dumped $plist->toXML() to a log/console to make sure you've generated the expected content?

Comment: From where does these CF* PHP classes come from?

Comment: sorry error i am getting is unexpected character o at line 1

Comment: object(CFArray)#1 (2) {
  ["iteratorPosition:protected"]=>
  int(0)
  ["value:protected"]=>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output there is not a plist; it's the internal representation of a CFPropertyList.  Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html for a short sample plist.

Your problem is that $plist->toXML() does not modify $plist; it returns a string of the XML representation of the $plist object. Change:

```
$plist->toXML();
var_dump($plist);
```

to

```
$xml = $plist->toXML();
var_dump($xml);
```